# How to schedule a JSON file import into the MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to figure out the best way to schedule a job that would import files into MySQL's Database. I'm using MySQL Workbench for that.

As of now, I'm simply using the Import Wizard, but I saw that there is no native scheduler for this task.

I reckon I can use the Task Scheduler on Windows for that, but because I'm fairly new to SQL, I don't know the best query to schedule such job.

I don't know if it makes a difference that one set of files will be JSON formatted while the other will be SQL.

Comment: As the Import Wizard is rather ManDraulic, a scheduled task could not answer all the questions. Are you also able to write code, PHP maybe or something similiar?

Comment: Q: Are the imported files always in the same format? What do you mean one set is JSON and the other SQL? An example of database schema and file formats in question is ALWAY a great idea in your question

Comment: Task scheduler is only one part of the problem: how do you plan to automate the GUI of mysql workbench to perform the import? If you need GUI automation, then you have to have a GUI user logged in, otherwise task scheduler can't run a GUI application and you still need to figure out how you automate the GUI actions. Writing a script to perform the import and scheduling that with task scheduler is a better option and is on topic here on SO - as long as you don't want us to write the whole script for you from scratch.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yea about that. It's two databases that I want to schedule import files into. One is for JSON imports, and the other is for SQL imports. So it's always gonna be same type for either of those.

Comment: Do you code? PHP for example

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't know much of PHP either :/

Comment: @Shadow so as I understand, writing a script for import is a must now, as I won't be able to target GUI with Task Scheduler, and the only option is to schedule an SQL query that imports the files right? Is it maybe better to omit the MySQL Workbench client in general and access the database differently? Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: mysql workbench is GUI tool and is therefore intended to be used by us humans, as opposed to scripts. I'm not aware that you can import json data from a file via sql script to a mysql database at the moment. You either need to convert your json data into a flat file and use load data infile sql statement or you need a script that can process a json file and connect to mysql to import the data. Most popular programming / script languages support mysql (you may need to install a mysql driver).